# Is this function recursive?

Tags: javascript, recursion

Can I apply `handleMsg` to the onclick handler from within `handleMsg` without recursion issues?

```
var state = 0;    

var handleMsg = function(num) {
    state = state + num;

    render(
        h("div", [
            if ((state % 2) == 1) {
                h("span", "the number is odd!"),
            } else {
                h("span", "the number is even!"), 
            }   
            h("button", {onclick: function(){ handleMsg(1) }}, "increment"),
            h("button", {onclick: function(){ handleMsg(-1) }}, "decrement"),
        ])
    );
};
```

Comment: have you tried it? does it work? do you get some errors?

Comment: @Nina - Its just a contrived example. I'm not sure how to view stack size in javascript... currently trying to figure that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you bind `onclick` with:

```
{onclick: handleMsg(1)}
```

you're assigning the result of calling `handleMsg` which may cause infinite recursion.

I guess that you want to invoke this function when clicked, so do it with:

```
{onclick: () => handleMsg(1)}
```

Without arrow function it can be done with:

```
{onclick: function () { handleMsg(1) }}
```

or as @DontVoteMeDown posted:

```
{onclick: handleMsg.bind(null, 1)}
```

Comment: thanks. Yeah, dumb mistake in the example. I didn't mean to apply the result of handleMsg to the onclick handler. Edited my example.  So, my silly question is... why is this not recursive? Am I losing my mind?

Comment: @ErikLott what do you mean by *recursive* ? It breaks the chain behaviour you'd spect to happen or what? Because the way you're using the function is not essentially *recursion*. A recursive function have to call itself within its code. Check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_function).

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown - dumbest.. question.. ever.. To my defence, I've been writing purely functional ml for the past 4 months, and my mind started to panic looking at this javascript code... Thanks for hanging in there.

Comment: @ErikLott haha no problem mate.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can, but you need to change the way you are binding the click event. If you do like that, the `handleMsg(1)` will be executing the function right there instead of in the click event. To bind a function with a parameter, you have to use `.bind`:

```
onclick: handleMsg.bind(null, 1)
```